# No-index of specific url's

Tags: indexing, index

I have a few problems with indexed pages, therefore i want to no-index a few url's with problems.

/brand/index/
/nieuw/

So these 2 url's and also all other url's below, for example /brand/index/color/... and /nieuw/brand/...

Who can help me and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**  In the backend when editing a **product/category/cms** go to the tab design and add the following to custom layout:

```
 <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><meta>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</meta></action>
  </reference>
```

**Method 2:** You can also set it by using observer using this event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` like this:

```
public function setRobots($observer) 
{
     $controller = $observer->getAction();
     $fullActionName = $controller->getFullActionName();
     if ($fullActionName == 'catalog_product_view') { //if on product page
          $product = Mage::registry('product'); //access the current product if needed
          if (your condition here) { //condition to set the robots to noindex, nofollow
              $observer->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
          }
     }
}
```

**Method 3:** IF you are using custom modlue then it can be added through your controller action like:

```
 <?php
    class Arunendra_Athletes_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
        public function IndexAction() {

            $this->loadLayout();    
            // change robotos with yours 
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
          $this->renderLayout(); 

        }
    }
```

**Note:** Change the robots with yours

Comment: Thanks for your help! But can it also be fixed by adding the next lines to robots.txt? Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /index.php
Disallow: /index.html
Disallow: /brand/index/*
Disallow: /nieuw/*